# whats the recommended Data access layer design pattern if i will apply ado entity frame work later?

Tags: linq-to-sql, design-patterns, entity-framework, data-access-layer

I am creating a website and using Linq to SQl as a data access layer, and i am willing to make the website can work on both linq to sql and ado entity framework, without changing many things in the other layers: business logic layer or UI layer,

Whats the recommended pattern to achieve this goal? can you explain in brief how to do that?

**UPDATE**

As answered below that repository pattern will help me a lot,

i checked nerd dinner website and understood it, but i found this code inside:

```
public class DinnersController : Controller {

        IDinnerRepository dinnerRepository;

        //
        // Dependency Injection enabled constructors

        public DinnersController()
            : this(new DinnerRepository()) {
        }

        public DinnersController(IDinnerRepository repository) {
            dinnerRepository = repository;
        }
```

Which means as i understood that it declare a dinnerRepository using the interface IDinnerRepository , and in the constructor gave it the DinnerRepository, which will be in my case for example the linq to sql implementation,

My question is if i need to switch to ado.net entity framework, i will need to edit this constructor line or there is a better solution for this?

**Update 2**

Where should i put this Respository Interface and the classes which implement it in my solution, in the data access layer or in the business layer?

Comment: No, the constructor contract will not change at all. The changes will all be in the implementation of the class that actually implements IDinnerRepository, hidden from view of those who call the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Repository pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) is a good choice.  If you implement it as an interface; then you can change out the concrete classes and not have to change anything else.

The [Nerd Dinner walkthrough](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) has an excellent example of the Repository pattern (with interface).

The code you listed there would go in your controller (if you were doing an MVC Application); and you create any class you wanted so long as it implemented the `IDinnerRepository` interface (or you could have something like an `IRepository` interface if you wanted to design an interface that everyone had to implement that did the basic CRUD actions, and then implement specific interfaces if you needed more (but let's not go interface crazy).

If you're 'tiering' your application, then that part would go in the "Business Logic" layer, and the Repository would be in the "Data Access Layer".  That constructor contract would be the 'loosely' coupled part.

Comment: please check my update in the question body, i tried to explain my problem above.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using a minor variation on the "Repository" pattern. I picked it up from the excellent Nerd Dinner tutorial. You can find [the whole tutorial here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) and the [code is on Codeplex](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).

Don't let all the MVC put you off if your not in an MVC situation, the underlying encapsulation of Linq2SQL is a good one. In a recent update of a codebase I went from Linq2SQL to Linkq2EF and all the changes were nicely dealt with in the repository, no outside code had to be touched.

It is also worth noting that the RIA Services stuff comes with a similar pattern. You point it at Linq2Sql or Linq2EF and it build you a basic layer over it complete with CRUD. That layer is in source code so you could just rip it out and use it in a non RIA project but I just leave it as is and link to it in other projects so I use the layer even if I ignore the over-the-wire abilities.

Comment: can you give me url to know more about this RIA Services stuff and its using as you said?

Comment: Brad Abrams has a 23 part tutorial on RIA and issues around it. As you read that you will see that you can simply add a reference to the site he is building and use the RIA Domainservice class directly in other projects.

http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/10/amazing-business-apps-example-updated-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update.aspx

Comment: Whay did you do about the business entities and the dto entities - did you use a mapper to go between the two types of object?