# How RIA Services can help me while creating data access and logic layers?

Tags: ria, n-tier-architecture, data-access-layer

in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384396/whats-the-recommended-data-access-layer-design-pattern-if-i-will-apply-ado-entity/1384463#1384463) he said that i can use RIA services while creating my 3 tiers solution, how it can help me and how it can save me time, because when i checked it on msdn i found that RIA is something tied to silver light, while i am creating a normal asp.net website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distringuish between **RIA** and **RIA Services**

In the broadest sensse RIA (generally Rich Internet Applications) are implemented in technologies such as Silverlight, Dojo etc, give a really ncie UI experience in the browser (tier 1)

They will usually need to get data from somewhere, so you write  service on a server somewhere. (tier 2). That in turn may actually go to some database or other data source (tier 3).

RIA Services is making the task of building that tier 2, service tier, logic easier. The kinds of services you build there are in principle reusable by many clients, but in fact you tend to find that certain patterns of service work particularly well for RIA UIs, and so the RIA Services are targeted at satisfying those needs.